# Protractor to loop through array and open the url

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying a piece of code to loop through an `id`s array to check different links and each tiem the same url must be opened. Something like this:

```
    url = "www.google.com" 
    linksarray.forEach(function (linkChosen){
          browser.get(url);
          console.log("url", url)
          element(by.id(linkchosen).click()
          // perform some action to check if link was clicked
          console.log("here")
          browser.refresh() //should clear the actions performed by clicking on the link
          console.log("done")
     }
```

But the page opens only once and the second loops fails saying it cannot perform the actions as the element was never clicked (but the url was not refreshed and opened again) - What is that i am missing here. Also even before opening the url first time, the foreach prints `here` and `done` twice (since 2 elements in the array). How to make it wait and execute it along with the browser flow?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that you are executing asynchronous code. For example `browser.get(url)` is asynchronous and returns a `Promise` object. Your code is finished executing before `browser.get()` even opens the url.

When handling with `Promises` you can either use `then()` resp. `catch()` or `await`. Following 2 snippets do exactly the same.

1) Using `then`:

```
// ...
t.it('myTest', function() {
 linksarray.forEach(function (linkChosen) {
    browser.get(url).then(function() { 
      console.log("url", url);
      element(by.id(linkchosen).click().then(function () {
        console.log('element clicked');
        browser.refresh().then(function () {
          console.log("done");
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

2) Using `await` (Can be used within every async function.)

```
// ...
t.it('myTest', async function() {
  await linksArray.forEach(async function(linkChosen) {
    await browser.get(url);
    console.log("url", url);
    await element(by.id(linkChosen)).click();
    console.log('element clicked');
    await browser.refresh();
    console.log("done");
  });
}
```

You should consider taking some time and learning basics about `Promise` class. It's necessary knowledge when working with asynchronous code.